# Can `:exports` be set independently for inline org-babel code blocks?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

In my `org-mode` document I use both src blocks and inline code blocks. When exporting to LaTeX, is there a way to set `:exports both` for the src blocks, but `:exports results` for the inline code? Right now, the exported document looks a weird when exporting e.g.

```
#+begin_src R
datafile <- "some/file.csv"
#+end_src
We use the file src_R{datafile}
```

because the text will read "We use the file datafile some/file.csv". Of course I can manually add the exports statements to the inline code like this
`src_R[:exports results]{datafile}`, but that becomes tedious very quickly.